# Shaarei Teshuvah 3-228 - requires rebuke for the sake of the listeners - but how do they know if done in private

Tags: rabbeinu-yonah

In Shaarei Teshuvah (ST) Rabbeinu Yonah (RY) states that there are times when it's permitted to publicly disparage someone (e.g. a thief who has not returned the money or asked forgiveness).  However, in 3-228 he states that even when allowed there is a separate concern of אבק לשה"ר if people suspect him of speaking לשון הרע (LH).  Accusing him of חניפה and LH unless it's said בפניו (as per Arachin 16) - which he explains to mean that he 1st rebuked the sinner directly.

Q - isn't rebuke supposed to be given privately (as per RambaM Hil Daos 6:8) - if so, how would the public know that he rebuked?
(he mentions תוכחת מגולה - does that mean public rebuke?  i.e. that he argues on the RambaM?)

Also, worth noting that in עליות דרבינו יונה on the Gemara - he explains בפניו differently (and not even needed to be said directly).  Why the diff?

> והנה יחשד המספר בזה ויתן אותו כמספר לשון הרע. ויאמרו אמרו. גם אם אמת היה הדבר היה ראוי לגלות אוזן החוטא למוסר בתחלה. ועל דבר אשר לא קדם לו תוכחות יחשדנו שומעו לאמר. כי לא היה אומר כל אלה בפני חבירו וכי הוא מחניף לו. כענין שנאמר [הושע ד׳:ד׳] אך איש אל ירב ואל יוכה איש. ונהנה לדבר באשמת העם אשר בהעוותם ישמח ובקלונם יתכבד שלא בפניהם. ודומה לבעל לשון הרע. ובו דבק. מן האבק. ועוד יאמרו בני אדם אין הדברים כנים ומלבו הוא בודאם.** ואם לא איפוא מדוע לא גלה על עונו בפניו ראשונה והעלים ממנו.
> על **כן אמרו רבותינו** כל דבר אשר יאמר **בפני בעליו** אין בו דרך לשון הרע. רצונו לומר - כי אם הקדים לחבירו **תוכחת מגולה** על מעשהו ולא הקשיב על דבריו, אחרי כן יוכל להודיע לבני אדם אשמת האיש ורוע מוסרו. ואל יחשד כי יחפוץ לתת דופי בחברו.

Comment: Based on the continuation of the text, it seems like this is contingent on the reputation of the one making the statements. If he is someone that is known not to mince words, and unhesitatingly says the same things whoever he is front of, then no such תוכחה מגולה  is necessary, as he is not someone that would be suspected of לשון הרע (i.e. saying things behind others back), but if he is the type of person who would perhaps be so suspect, then he must first engage in תוכחה מגולה in order to allay this suspicion... presumably both types of individuals would have to first engage in תוכחה מסותרת.

Comment: When you publicly rebuke, you say “I already spoke to him privately, and he refuses to listen, so now I need to do it publicly”

Comment: @Chatzkel - nice and simple answer - thanks - please list it as an answer

Comment: @Deuteronomy - Are you saying he first rebukes privately, and then if unsuccessful - repeats it publicly?

Comment: @Chaim yes that is what I am suggesting. However the necessity for the issuance of a second public rebuke would depend on the publicly known character of the one giving rebuke (i.e. if he is one that would be חושד as a בעל לשון הרע).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple reading would seem to mean that when he does a public rebuke, he would preface it with “I already rebuked him in private and it hasn’t worked, therefore I am now doing it publicly”.